# Texturing backgrounds in Java Swing everywhere, not just in panels

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I want to make a GUI with Java swing/JPanel with a textured background. I found a few tutorials on the topic that texture within the boundaries of the control its being applied to, like this:

[image]

That's easy enough. I can't figure out how to apply textures, (not necessarily the same texture) elsewhere, like on the tabs title bar, the background, scroll bars... basically everywhere that's still yellow.

How do I do this? Does this require making my own 'Look and Feel'?

Comment: *"Does this require making my own 'Look and Feel'?"*  Either that, or manipulating the `UIManager`..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have no experience doing either of those things. Can you suggest a starting point to learn about it?  My current understanding suggests that modifying `UIManager` would farther with platform dependance and therefore easier.

Comment: *"Can you suggest a starting point to learn about it?"*  'X java tutorial' in your favorite search engine, where X is either 'uimanager' or 'look and feel'..

Comment: @AndrewThompson No luck finding stuff specifically for textures. I can do `UIManager.put("Button.background", Color.GRAY);` that sets a solid color background. put takes `(Object key,Object value)`. It looks like the keys are being matched to those inside the Look and Feel. So the Look and Feel is also probably responsible for validating which `Object`s are acceptable. In other words, certain Look and Feels might support `Color`s only and others accept some sort of texture class in its place. If I understand correctly of course. Still looking...

Comment: `JTattoo` is apparently a collection of Look and Feels which apparently takes "backgroundPattern" as a "theme property"

Comment: Now you might write an answer to your own question..  :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Didn't work. Got JTattoo "texture" theme loaded, attempted to change backgroundPattern as shown in example program. No change, no error, no readout, limited documentation, and they expect me to purchase it if I use it for something profitable. I have no more results then when I started and still don't know which method to pursue. Can you share anything on this topic that would help? You know, instead of telling me to Google it and to answer my own question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components have a variety of functions named `paint___` that control the drawing of various parts. I overrode these and tiled `Graphics.drawImage()` in the parts responsible for the background.